# Contents of request.endpoint[:5]

Tags: python, flask, request

I'm going through Miguel Grinbergs Flask book and at one point he uses the following line:

```
request.endpoint[:5] != 'auth.'
```

I know `[:5]` is a slice operation, but I'm not sure why it is being used here.  What does the list consist of that we only want elements 0-5?

Comment: why don't you `print(request.endpoint)` and see by yourself?

Comment: I tried that in python shell but got "NameError: name 'request' is not defined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does the list consist of that we only want elements 0-5?

To be precise, `request.endpoint` is not a list, it's a string. And it doesn't matter what the rest of it contains, the code is only concerned with it beginning with `'auth.'`:

```
('auth.somethingsomething'[:5] == 'auth.') is True
```

`request.endpoint` is the name the current view function was registered as, for example `auth.login` is the name of the `def login():` view. Views that have a prefix like `prefix.` were registered on a blueprint, which groups related views. So the code is checking if the current view being handled is part of the `auth` blueprint.

If you're curious about what value it contains, you can add a debugging breakpoint to the code and inspect it:

```
# ... previous app code ...
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
request.endpoint[:5] != 'auth.'
```

Then run and test the code. When it hits that point, it'll pause execution and give you a `pdb` shell, which will let you look at the `request` object and its `endpoint` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

you can checking on terminal by

```
venv $ python manage.py shell
import flask from request
print(request.endpoint)
```